# How to make fake anisotropic shader

Tags: materials

How do I make these kinds of materials?

https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/010/258/877/original/dzung-phung-dinh-pisciasa-clothesshader-sample.gif?1523458872

https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/010/258/888/original/dzung-phung-dinh-pisciasa-anisotropic-sample.gif?1523458877

To be clearer I want to make something like this:

https://80.lv/articles/stylized-character-production-techniques-in-ue4/
(the stylized anisotropic shader part)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add lightvector to cameravector then normalize it.
Next, project that vector to normal-tangent plane.
The vector you created is fake normal.
This normal create fake Anisotropic specular.

This enable realtime anisotropic specular effect in blender 2.79.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough because you didn't specify the version of Blender you want to use.

If its Blender 2.79 internal render,

All you just need to do is to click on "Tangent shading" under the material panel

Comment: I'd like it to be Cycles.The examples were done in Unreal engine, so it's a rasterization engine

Answer (score 0):

These could be done procedurally. The last one seems simple, a principled bsdf, metallic: 1, and then you set the anisotropic amount you like. If it had this radial or line reflection it is called anisotropic.

The second one seems to be more complicated and would require lots of nodes. A good start would be to use voronoi as a base. And play around with vectors. This part really seems to complicated to put into words as it requires lots of fiddling around.

The different layers could be achieved using a layer weight node. Plugging the facing value into a color ramp with the desired colors would give you the effect. Afterwards you could use color mix to overlay or add this with the voronoi pattern underneath. This color output you then plug into the color input of the principled shader and I crease the clear coat value with some anisotropic to give the shine effect.

Or you can use two shader nodes with an add shader:

The voronoi pattern without anisotropic under the other one with anisotropic

Comment: Is there a way to make the anisotropic follow a fake light source?
So far how you described the effect needs a real light source and would change the further the object is from a light source. Which is okay, but I would also like to know how to make it work without lightsources

Comment: i just came to that thought on the fly so it migth be flawed, you can try to get a single point as color input,mask out an area with some color ramp nodes, and plug a texture coordinate node with the reflection vector into the vector of an shader with the masked out are as color input.